# Add missing data xts and match them with a 0 value

Tags: r, xts

I have problems with missing data, there are missing some minute values as you can see below...I use as.POSIXct to set the date as an index. How to add the missing Date to get a full ts and match them with a "Num_tweets" of 0 ?

start = 2012-12-01 12:52:00
end = 2012-12-01 13:02:00

My data looks like this:

```
 Date, Num_tweets
2012-12-01 12:52:00, 3
2012-12-01 12:53:00, 3
2012-12-01 12:54:00, 1
2012-12-01 12:55:00, 2
2012-12-01 12:56:00, 3
2012-12-01 12:59:00, 3
2012-12-01 13:00:00, 2
2012-12-01 13:02:00, 1
```

What I expect :

```
Date, Num_tweets
2012-12-01 12:52:00, 3
2012-12-01 12:53:00, 3
2012-12-01 12:54:00, 1
2012-12-01 12:55:00, 2
2012-12-01 12:56:00, 3
2012-12-01 12:57:00, 0
2012-12-01 12:58:00, 0
2012-12-01 12:59:00, 3
2012-12-01 13:00:00, 2
2012-12-01 13:01:00, 0
2012-12-01 13:02:00, 1
```

How can I do that ? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `complete`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1  %>% 
 mutate(Date = as.POSIXct(Date)) %>%
 complete(Date = full_seq(Date, period = 60), fill = list(Num_tweets = 0))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 11 × 2
   Date                Num_tweets
   <dttm>                   <int>
 1 2012-12-01 12:52:00          3
 2 2012-12-01 12:53:00          3
 3 2012-12-01 12:54:00          1
 4 2012-12-01 12:55:00          2
 5 2012-12-01 12:56:00          3
 6 2012-12-01 12:57:00          0
 7 2012-12-01 12:58:00          0
 8 2012-12-01 12:59:00          3
 9 2012-12-01 13:00:00          2
10 2012-12-01 13:01:00          0
11 2012-12-01 13:02:00          1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("2012-12-01 12:52:00", "2012-12-01 12:53:00", 
"2012-12-01 12:54:00", "2012-12-01 12:55:00", "2012-12-01 12:56:00", 
"2012-12-01 12:59:00", "2012-12-01 13:00:00", "2012-12-01 13:02:00"
), Num_tweets = c(3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by merging the xts object with a zero-width xts object that has the index values you want.

```r
library(xts)
# using df1 from akrun's answer
x <- xts(df1$Num_tweets, as.POSIXct(df1$Date))

one_min_seq <- xts(, seq(start(x), end(x), by = "1 min"))
y <- merge(Num_tweets = x, one_min_seq, fill = 0)
print(y)
##                     Num_tweets
## 2012-12-01 12:52:00          3
## 2012-12-01 12:53:00          3
## 2012-12-01 12:54:00          1
## 2012-12-01 12:55:00          2
## 2012-12-01 12:56:00          3
## 2012-12-01 12:57:00          0
## 2012-12-01 12:58:00          0
## 2012-12-01 12:59:00          3
## 2012-12-01 13:00:00          2
## 2012-12-01 13:01:00          0
## 2012-12-01 13:02:00          1
```